# passing an javascript object from cakephp view to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am developing a website using cakephp, and I'd like to pass a javascript object in view back to the controller.  I know that using a form could be easier but I need to do this customized.

So here's the object ('annotation' and 'article_id' are real column names in the database, annotation and article_id are both variables containing data):

```
var postdata = {
    'annotation' : annotation,
    'article_id' : article_id
};
```

What method in the view should I use?  Is it .post?

And how should I program the corresponding controller to correctly receive the object and extract data from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do an [ajax](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/) request.