# Passing JavaScript Variables from a CakePHP View to Controller

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP and plan on developing an application with it. I was wondering if there is a way to pass JavaScript variables created in a View to it's corresponding Controller?

For example, if I generated two coordinate variables using the HTML5 Geolocation JavaScript API in a View, how could I pass these JS variables to a corresponding Controller in order to use them to query a database in a function?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456940/passing-an-javascript-object-from-cakephp-view-to-controller?rq=1

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456940/passing-an-javascript-object-from-cakephp-view-to-controller?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
Make a request to that controller action and send those values. The controller should send back a response that you can use in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Use AJAX
- Use JavaScript to submit a form
- Use JavaScript to redirect to a URL with ?get variables

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax and send javascript values as query string in your URL.

In controller, you can get those values using PHP way $_Get['name'] or using cake way $this->request->query['variable_name'];

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

basically you need to send the data to the controller, in any way you like to.